# How many sequences there are of n digits?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many sequences are there of $n$ digits $(0, 1, ..., 9)$ in which no pair of digits consecutive are the same?

Comment: $10$ choices for the first digit.  $9$ choices for each following digit since they can't match what came before.  Apply rule of product and conclude.

Comment: To first digit 10, for second 9, for third digit 9 again? because only said in pair cant be the same or im lost?

Comment: First digit in $10$ ways.  Second digit since it can't be the same as the first, whatever the first happened to be, will have $9$ choices.  The specific choices themselves will vary depending on what was already selected, but the *number* is nine regardless.  Then, the third has $9$ choices again because it can't be whatever was selected for the second.  Again, the types of choices can vary, but the *number* of choices which is the only thing we care about here doesn't

Comment: Thank you! then if im understand there are $10*9^{n}$

Comment: Almost.  How long of a sequence do we have again?  How many times did we have $10$ choices and how many times did we have $9$ choices?

Comment: The first digit you had $10$ choices for.  The rest of the digits you had $9$ choices for.  So how many *times* did you have a choice of $9$.  (Hint:  It *wasnt* $n$ times....)

Comment: Oh its true for 10 times are 9 then its $10*9^{n-1}$

Comment: Bingo.  There are $10$ choices for the first digit.  ANd $9$ choices for the remaining $n-1$ digits.  SO there or $10\times\underbrace{9\times 9\times ....\times 9}_{n-1\ times} = 10*9^{n-1}$ total choices.

Answer (score 0):

$$\_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ .... n \ times$$

Now we have to fill in these $n$ gaps. The first gap can be filled with either ( say $A$ ) of all the $10$ options. So we have $10$ options here.

$$\color{red}{A} \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \  ....(n-1) \ gaps \ left$$

The next gap can be filled with any digit ( say $B$ ) other than $A$. So, we have ($10-1$ ) = $9$ options here.

$$\color{red}{A} \ \color{green}{B} \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \ \_ \  ....(n-2) \ gaps \ left$$

Now, for the $3^{rd}$ gap we can fill it with any digit ($\color{purple}{C} $) other than $B$ ($A$ becomes available now). So we have $9$ options here.

From here, you can see how each gap other than the first one has $9$ options, while the first one has $10$ options.

Simply apply the rule of product here to get the total cases as :

$$= \color{red}{10} \times (\color{green}{9} \times \color{purple}{9} \times ...(n-1) \ times)$$

$$= 10 \times 9^{n-1} $$